# Error al solicitar Petición AJAX con JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, rest, cors

Tengo un problema al realizar una petición AJAX a una API de dominios externa, ya que recibo un error de CORS:

> Request header field X-TOKEN is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Pero probando con PHP utilizando CURL, o con herramientas como Postman no obtengo ese error.
Al analizar la respuesta desde chrome Recibo esto

[image: Cuerpo de la respuesta en Chrome]

El código con el que realizo la petición es el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "get",
    data: {
        'sld': dominio_sld,
        'tld': dominio_tld
    },
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        'X-TOKEN': user_key
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        beforeSend();
    },
    success: function (response) {
        afterSend();
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        afterSend();
        showError();
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    // Mas código
});
```

El problema esta en el código o es un error que ocurre por algo del servidor?

Answer (score 1):

La solución mas fácil que encontré fue crear un pequeño backend en PHP que realizara las peticiones a la API salteándose el error de CORS y con esos datos usarlo en mi FrontEnd llamando al backend con AJAX en JQuery.